# How To Watch a JQuery Selector Using AngularJS scope.$watch() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm writing a directive which needs to watch for elements that get updated with a particular class, say `.ng-invalid`. As you know, `.ng-invalid` is added to form elements which are invalid.

I need to watch these elements to determine if the class was added or removed.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you share your code with fiddle or plunker demo

Comment: Here is a dummy fiddle for my requirement. http://jsfiddle.net/aW7FD/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could $watch a function that gets the length of `$(".ng-invalid")`:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return $(".ng-invalid").length;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal !== oldVal) {
       console.log('changed!', newVal, oldVal);
       // do your changes here
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Aenh4/).  In the fiddle, I added `ng-minlength="2"` to the first `input`.  Type two characters into that field to see the $watch trigger.

Comment: This is really elegant! Worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

Would it be sufficient for your purposes to watch the `$invalid` attribute of [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController)? This will notify you of changes to the form's holistic invalid status, for example:

```js
// Somewhere in your directive; formCtrl is the FormController
scope.$watch(function() {
  return formCtrl.$invalid;
}, function(isInvalid, wasInvalid) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: No this is not sufficient for my requirement :-(